# Programmatically execute evil-ex move command

Tags: evil

I'd like to execute an evil-ex command from another command. Specifically, I'd like to do `:'<,'>move'>+1` but when I do, it doesn't quite do the right thing. Instead of moving the text down, it moves it one line from the top of the file.

Here's what I'm using:

```
(defun evil-visual-move-line-down ()
  (interactive)
  (evil-ex-call-command
   (evil-ex-range (evil-ex-line (evil-ex-marker "<") nil)
                  (evil-ex-line (evil-ex-marker ">") nil)) "move" "'>+1"))
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "J") 'evil-visual-move-line-down)
```

Comment: Please don't.  Evil's authors [recommend writing extensions to it in standard Emacs Lisp](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/485/not-really-a-issue-but-how-could-i-get#comment-15695737), not by composing its parts.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've made some more progress, but got stuck again. I emailed the mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Frank Fischer himself:

```
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "J"
  (concat ":m '>+1" (kbd "RET") "gv=gv"))
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "K"
  (concat ":m '<-2" (kbd "RET") "gv=gv"))
```

Comment: If this post solved your problem, could you accept your own answer so we can mark it as done, please?